# JNA multiple void pointers inside a C struct by reference

Tags: java, c, pointers, struct, jna

In my current project I have to implement the function of native c libs in a java project.
I'm using JNA. And reached some good results so far.
Now I'm stuck on the following problem.

I have to call the native c function:

```
int retrieveResult(ResultStruct * pResult)
```

Where the Struct is defined like followed:

```
typedef struct tag_ResultStruct
{
const void *pBuffer;
int sizeX;
int sizeY;
} ResultStruct;
```

In Java I created a class representing the struct:

```
public class ResultStruct extends Structure{
   public Pointer pBuffer;
   public int sizeX;
   public int sizeY;

   @Override
   protected List<String> getFieldOrder(){
      return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"pBuffer", "sizeX", "sizeY"});
   }

   public ResultStruct(){

   }
}
```

I'm calling the Native C Method with

```
private interface MyCLib extends Library{
   MyCLib INSTANCE = Native.load("myclib", MyCLib.class);
   int retrieveResult(ResultStruct pResult);
}
ResultStruct resultStruct = new ResultStruct();
resultStruct.pBuffer = new Memory(bufferLen);
int res = MyCLib.INSTANCE.retrieveResult(resultStruct);
```

Now I'm able to retrieve the expected values from sizeX, sizeY and pBuffer with

```
resultStruct.pBuffer.getByteArray(0, bufferLen);
```

Now I' extending my struct like the following:

```
typedef struct tag_ResultStruct
{
const void* pContext;
const void *pBuffer;
int sizeX;
int sizeY;
} ResultStruct;
```

And my Java Structure:

```
public class ResultStruct extends Structure{
   public Pointer pContext;
   public Pointer pBuffer;
   public int sizeX;
   public int sizeY;

   @Override
   protected List<String> getFieldOrder(){
      return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"pContext", "pBuffer", "sizeX", "sizeY"});
   }

   public ResultStruct(){

   }
}
```

Problem is, i don't want to make use of pContext. So I don't know which size it should have and therefore i don't initialize the pointer.
Now when i try to retrieve the values from the buffer by calling:

```
resultStruct.pBuffer.getByteArray(0, bufferLen);
```

I don't get the expected values from buffer.

#### Question

How to deal with more than dynamic memory field inside a Structure passed by reference when using JNA?
It is possible to leave Pointer uninitialized inside the Structure?

I Appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a really cool set of JNA based samples here: https://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/

Comment: Thank you. I already looked at these examples. But there is no example for retrieving the array inside the structs when struct is passed by reference.

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo070

Comment: What does your API tell you you are supposed to pass for the context pointer?  It should be very similar where you allocate a `Memory` object with the necessary values.

Comment: Oo.oO's example solved the problem perfectly. Thank you.
My own example is now working.

But I still encounter a problem when using the API from the third party software.

It is the Pylon C API from Basler. The struct should contain the image-data when a frame was grabbed. I always get an invalid memory acces error, when trying to get the ByteArray from the pBuffer Pointer.
The Documentation says the context pointer is a pointer to "additional context information". In their sample they're using an integer index value, casting it to (void*).

Comment: Please note that structure packing may play a role here. It might happen that your data are aligned and read incorrectly. I suggest to play with `#pragma pack` and `setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);`. In case you have no access to sources (of the library) it might be better to access it using `JNI` where you have more control over details. You can decide (inside native part of code) how exactly your data will be mapped between `C` and `Java`.

Comment: Is it possible to combine jna and jni in an elegant way? I want to avoid writing the whole wrapper in jni.
I also thought about writing an own small lib which encapsulates the function which retrieves the result. But I don't know whether this is a safe way to deal with my problem.

The interesting thing is, there is a second function which also allows to retrieve the buffer with a direct pointer (withou using the struct). Besides the some other disadvantages of this function, i can get the result data by mapping a preallocateted  (in java) byte array to the void* parameter of the function.

Comment: Some details about the mentioned function. Besides a pure void* pointer (void*buffer) it has the result struct parameter.
Using the function in a C sample, the pure pointer `buffer` and the buffer pointer inside the result struct has the same adress value.

Comment: After I talked with a member of technical support at Basler, he told me, the memory where pBuffer points to gets released when the function gets out of scope. So he suggested (like it would be common, when dealing with this function) to copy the memory to an own array.
So I have to write some c code, which wraps this function.
What would be your suggestion, when I want to keep the other functionality in JNA?
Should I write a own small lib, which wraps this function and use it in JNA. Or would it be bett to write the wrapper in JNI. Or should I write the complete library wrapper in JNI? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, who replied to my question. You set me on the right track.

## Answer

Here is the answer to my question. Maybe it may help someone other encountering the same or a similar problem.

### Problem

In the library which I use (Pylon C API from Basler) it is mentioned that you have to register one or more output buffers. It is done by allocating the buffer and register the pointer of that array.

Usually I map a byte array (`byte[] buffer = new byte[size]`) to a uchar* or void* buffer. This works, when the buffer is filled directly in you c function (like in the sample that Oo.oO gave me).

But in the context of the API that I'm using, the pointer gets filled a bit later after it was registeres (it gets filled, when image data is available).
I'm not an expert, but I think the java byte array, doesn't work like a real pointer.

### Solution

I changed the buffer allocation in Java to

```
Pointer pBuffer = new Memory(size)
```

and mapped this Pointer to the void* buffer pointer, when registering it.
Now the buffer Pointer works as expected and I can retrieve the content of the buffer later by using

```
byte[] data = pBuffer.getByteArray(0, size)
```

This also works, when the pointer returned by the function `retrieveResult(...)` is inside a struct.